# How to use class variable inside inner function?

Tags: java, android, interface, android-location, nested-function

I want to use a class member from inside inner function

I have tried making the variable global but got the error 'class or interface expected'

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Add a marker in current location,
        // and move the map's camera to the same location.
        //Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION);
        }else {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                    wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                    /*LatLng sydney = new LatLng(wayLatitude, wayLongitude);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/
                }
            });
        }
```

I want to be able to do "googleMap.addMarker" inside the "OnSuccess" function.
How can I do it?

Comment: I think it should work but to know in detail of the issue, it would be good if you share the class code with related data. From the error it seems that you are missing to use `class` or `interface` keyword anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the googleMap argument as final:

```
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //...
}
```